# How to fix a syntax error with print in Python 3?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have installed bs4 and Python 3.4.4.

```
>>> print soup.prettify()
File "<stdin>", line 1
print soup.prettify()
         ^
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

Comment: How are you getting this `soup`?

Comment: what python version?

Comment: Python version 3.4.4

Comment: You [*just asked*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946391/please-help-me-with-this-syntax-error-using-bs4) this and got it closed as a dupe of the same question. Don't keep reposting your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `print` is a function, not a statement.

So, you want to call it as `print(soup.prettify())`.